# Copying data from CSV and outputting it into another

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I would like to do three things: import data from one CSV if the values in column 2 and 3 meet a criteria, translate this data based on a mapping key and output this translated data into a new CSV.

```
Sub in_out()



dim file_path as string
file_path = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
open file_path for input as #1
row_count = 0

sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Line_FromFile
    Line_Items = Split(Line_FromFile, ",")

    If Line_Item(2) = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value And Line_Item(3) = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2").Value Then


    ActiveCell.Offset(row_count, 0).Value = Line_Items(1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_count, 1).Value = Line_Items(2)

    row_count = row_count +1
    Loop

    else
    row_count = row_count +1
    Loop

    end if

    row_count = row_count +1
    Loop




Close #1

End sub
```

Comment: Try using `Option Excplicit` at the beginning of your module. That helps to prevent errors like using row_num instead of row_count... Don't rely on `activecell` too.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using SQL with an ADODB-Connection instead of VBA-only. With large CSVs, this should be considerably faster than looping each row.

An SQL-Statement like this one could do the trick.

```
SELECT * 
INTO [Text;DATABASE=L:\Out-Folder].tblOut.csv
FROM [Text;DATABASE=L:\In-Folder].tblIn.csv
WHERE column2 = criteria1 AND column2 = criteria2
```

Note that you need a [schema.ini-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describing the structure of you CSV. Those are reasonably easy and fast to set-up.

You then could either

a) run said SQL-query from directly from MS Access as an MS-Access query

or

b) run the SQL in MS Access-VBA like so:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * INTO ... FROM ... WHERE ..."
CurrentDb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
```

or

c) run it from Excel-VBA, if you have to use Excel. This would require you to set up an ADODB.Connection first, roughly like this:

```
Dim MyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyCmd As ADODB.Command

With MyConn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open yourDB.accdb
End With

With MyCmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = MyConn
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
End With

Set MyCmd = Nothing
Set MyConn = Nothing
```

General Remarks:

- be sure to backup your original CSV during developing
- Since you use the same filter-criteria for each row (Cells B2 and C2), adjusting the SQL is rather straight-forward and can be done by either reading the Cell-Contents like you did (in Excel) or, for example, using a UserForm (in Access).
- Note that in c), I first connected to an ACCDB called `yourDB.accdb`, which obviously senseless in my code, since you can directly connect to the textfiles with [the proper connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/). However, if you plan to do some Mapping, you could maintain your Mapping-Tables in said Access-Database and use them in your SQL (with a Join).
- In addition, I personally like the fact that in this case any path-information is contained inside the SQL-Statement, even if it has a slightly slower performance.

EDIT:
Naturally, if you would rather append data to the Output-CSV (rather than replace it), you could use an `INSERT`-Statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Text;DATABASE=L:\Out-Folder].tblOut.csv
SELECT *
FROM [Text;DATABASE=L:\In-Folder].tblIn.csv
WHERE column2 = criteria1 AND column2 = criteria2
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I hadn't considered using SQL/VBA because of some accessibility issues made VBA only the preferred choice.